# How to replace htmlentities using HTML Tags using PHP str_replace

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have a content like below.

I want the `<pre></pre>` to be converted to `<p> </p>`. But i'm not able achieve it. Below is an example

```
$content = "<pre>This is a pre text &#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs ";

print_r(str_replace(array('<pre>', '</pre>', '&#13;'),array('<p>', '</p>', '<br/>'),htmlspecialchars($content)));
```

But i get the output as it is. Can someone help me resolve. Thanks in advance

Comment: `<pre>This` give space between `<pre>` and `This` and try

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is the culprit. You are changing the `$content` before replacing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing `$content` before replacing the string.

```
$content = "<pre>This is a pre text &#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs ";

print_r(htmlspecialchars($content));

// returns    &lt;pre&gt;This is a pre text &amp;#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs
```

None of which matches your `str_replace`

Remove the `htmlspecialchars()` and you will get the output you wanted.

```
$content = "<pre>This is a pre text &#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs ";

print_r(str_replace(array('<pre>', '</pre>', '&#13;'),array('<p>', '</p>', '<br/>'),$content));

//returns    <p>This is a pre text <br/> I want to convert it to paragraphs
```

Comment: so i should remove `htmlspecialchars` is what your saying

Comment: Unless the words "Remove the `htmlspecialchars()`" means something different?

Comment: Or just swap the order and strreplace first followed by htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @doug OPs question said he wanted the result to be `<p> </p>`. This achieves that. `htmlspecialchars()` gives him `&lt;pre&gt; &lt;/pre&gt;` instead.

Comment: I assumed he also needed the string converted for what ever reason. Hence why he was using htmlspecialchars in the first place.

Comment: @luke i didn't read the line with remove. sorry. Thanks mate that solved.

Comment: No drama. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this to getting expected output.

```
<?php
    $content = "<pre>This is a pre text </pre> &#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs";
    print_r(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array('<pre>', '</pre>', '&#13;'),array('<p>', '</p>', '<br/>'),$content)));
?>
```

Comment: check it ,may be its to be match your desired output @jeeva

Answer (score -1):

You can get your desired output without removing the htmlspecialchars() function by doing something like this:

```
$content = "<pre>This is a pre text &#13; I want to convert it to paragraphs ";

print_r(str_replace(array('&lt;pre&gt;', '&lt;/pre&gt;', '&amp;#13;'),array('<p>', '</p>', '<br/>'),htmlspecialchars($content)));
```

Comment: That would give him `&lt;pre&gt; &lt;/pre&gt;`. In his question he said he wanted `<pre> </pre>`.

Comment: He said that he wants the <pre></pre> to be converted to <p></p>. And my code do that. I have just showed a way to get his result without removing the htmlspecialchars() function.